# Django Admin - Add a tabularInline section referred to another class (without foreign key)

Tags: django, django-models, database-design, foreign-keys, django-admin

I'm developing a Django Admin interface for a sort of ecommerce.

I have some database model linked using foreign key.

In Django Admin interface, I want to show a TabularInline section inside Customer page to show me all items buyed by a specific customer but I have a classic error about "foreign key" because Customer model and OrderItems model are not directly linked.

```
class Customer(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Account"
        verbose_name_plural = "Accounts"

    def email_user(self, subject, message):
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            'l@1.com',
            [self.email],
            fail_silently=False,
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name="order_user")

    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    total_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    order_key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    payment_option = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    billing_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-created",)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.created)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    product = models.ForeignKey(ToolTable,
                                related_name="order_items",
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

```
class ToolTable(models.Model):

       
    basic = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=False,
        unique=True,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_("basic"),
        help_text=_("format: required, unique, max-100"),
    )

    P_Name = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=False,
        unique=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_("P_Name"),
        help_text=_("format: required, max-100"),
    )

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.P_Name
```

- Considering that OrderItems is linked to Order that is linked to Customer, is it a good solution create a foreignKey in OrderItems model to link this class to Customer class?

- Maybe could be a redundancy issue?

- What could be the alternative solution holding my actual database structure?

(considering that I tried to retrive a method using list_display but I want data in TabularInline and not in column in the account main page)

This is an example of expected result but with different instances.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Implement tabular inline without foreign key is difficult.

If you want to tabular data of order-items user-wise. You can implement a simple solution.

First, make a button to view order-items in the list page of user. After clicking, you redirect to order-item admin changelist page, where you can see filtered result.

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(YourUserModel)
class YourUserModelAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    ...
    # add user_order_item is list_display
    list_display = ['user_order_item']
    def user_order_item(self, obj):
        redirect_url = "%s?order__user__id__exact=%s" % (reverse('admin:{}_{}_changelist'.format(self.opts.app_label, OrderItem._meta.model_name)), obj.id)
        return format_html('<a class="button" href="{}">View</a>', redirect_url)


@admin.register(OrderItem)
class OrderItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['full_name', 'order_key', 'total_paid', 'billing_status']
    list_filter = ['order__user']
```